# Does stm with non-adjacent registers do 32 bit writes?

Tags: arm

I am looking at a piece of ARM code that will write a pair of 32bit registers, like this:

```
ldm r9!, {r0, r1}
sub r8, r8, #2
stm r10!, {r0, r1}
```

When the r10 output pointer is word aligned but not always dword aligned, does the above code write one 64bit value? My reading of the docs makes me think that a 64bit value would be written in this case, but I am concerned about the case where the 8 word cache line might already contain 7 words and then this code does a 64bit write and splits half of one of the dwords over the end of the cache line.

I was thinking that if the stm were to do 2 32bit word writes instead, that might avoid the issue. So, my question is would using two non-adjacent registers force the stm to write 2 words as opposed to a dword?

```
ldm r9!, {r0, r2}
sub r8, r8, #2
stm r10!, {r0, r2}
```

Would the above code be basically the same as:

```
ldm r9!, {r0, r1}
sub r8, r8, #2
str r0, [r10], #4
str r1, [r10], #4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The register numbers you are writing from or reading two have nothing to do with the AMBA/AXI bus transaction.  The only connection is the quantity of data.

The question is a bit vague and I dont know enough about all the different implementations, but if you have a 64 bit AXI bus and your 64 bits of data are not being written to a 64 bit aligned address (this is perfectly legal, writing 2 registers to address 0x1004 for example) then it takes two bus transactions one for the first item on the unaligned address (0x1004) and one transaction for the other (0x1008).  Assuming you are using an aligned address then it will perform a single 64 bit transaction independent of the register numbers so long as there are two of them.

The cache is yet another, completely separate, topic.  I believe you will get two separate transactions if the address is not dword aligned, and those transactions will be handled separately by the cache.  Understand the L1 cache if you have one is inside the core and not on the AXI bus the L2 cache if present is on the outside of the core between the core and the vendors AXI memory controller.  So L1 behavior and L2 behavior can vary, I dont know what the cores interface to the L1 looks like and if and how it breaks up these transactions.  I suspect no matter what make or model of processor you are on if something crosses a cache line boundary at some point in the memory system or in the cache logic it has to break that transaction up and handle the two cache lines separately.

From what I have seen the stm/ldm turns the single instruction into separate bus transactions where necessary.  For example a 4 register write to 0x1004 turns into 3 separate transactions, a 32 bit at 0x1004, a 64 bit at 0x1008 and a 32 bit at 0x1010.  Doing that yourself just wastes instruction fetch cycles, use the stm in this case.